# How to use Deferred with a basic javascript function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to do something like the following:

```
dataservice.doThis(folderIds).then(doThat(setIds));
```

Where `doThis` and `doThat` don't return anything.  I'm reading up on Deferred and promises but haven't been able to get this working.  How can I tell `doThat` not to run until everything in `doThis` has completed?

Comment: Have you tried actually using `$.Deferred`? http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `then`, you'll need some kind of promise system (even if it means re-implementing it yourself).  You can't do it *without* having `doThis` return a promise, however (and it will really need to *resolve* that promise as well, with the IDs you need):

```
var dataservice = {
    doThis: function doThis(folderIds) {
        var future = new PromiseAPlusCompliantPromise();
        makeXHR("/some/endpoint",  // endpoint
                {folderIds: folderIds},  // data to send
            function sucess(setIds) {  // success handler
                future.resolve(setIds);
        });
        return future;  // Note that we do have to return a promise here
    }
};

function doThat(setIds) {
    // Do whatever here
    // No need to return anything
}

dataservice.doThis([1, 2, 3]).then(doThat);
```